# Rails: Validating an array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

#### Application

I am working on a college admissions system where a student can make an application to up to 5 courses. The way I have designed this is to have an *Application* model and a *CourseApplication* model. An application can consist of many course_applications:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Assosciations
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :course_applications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :course_applications
  has_one :reference

  # Validations
  validates :course_applications, presence: true

end
```

---

#### Course Application

```
class CourseApplication < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Intersection entity between course and application.
  # Represents an application to a particular course, has an optional offer

  # Associations
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :course
  has_one :offer, dependent: :destroy

end
```

---

I want to make sure that a student cannot apply to the same course twice. I have already done some research but have had no success. This is the UI for a student making an application:

[Screenshot of application form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KItF.png)

When a course is selected, the course id is added to an array of course ids:

```
def application_params
  params.require(:application).permit(:user, course_ids: [])
end
```

Right now a student can select the same course twice, I want to prevent them from doing this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you can send a `ajax` and fetch all the elements in your second choice, except the choice you already selected in your first choice.

Comment: Are the priorities important?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Ropeney's solution effectively solved the problem through back-end validations. I've still to create the front-end validation however. At the moment the form just resets without displaying an appropriate error message. Any help in writing these javascript validations would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the rails side, I would do on the `CourseApplication`

```
validates :course, uniqueness: { scope: :application }
```

For your reference this can be found at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Also suggest on the database side to make a migration

```
add_index :course_applications, [:course, :application], :unique => true
```

For the validating on the form you will have to write javascript to make sure two things are selected, this will just return an error when someone tries to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the validation and index stopped the application from being created when the same course was selected twice. I didn't understand the scope validations well enough to implement them myself.

Comment: I'll look into how to write that javascript, I don't know much js but I'll see how far I get.